# Dominant eigenvalue of next-generation matrix

Tags: dynamical-systems, biology

I came across an article that says the $R_0$-number is the dominant eigenvalue of the next generation matrix. So I started research and I think I understand what the next generation matrix is.

My question ist, why ist the dominant eigenvalue of the next generation matrix the expected number of new infections?